# Quasi-simmetric function and bi-Lipschitz functions

Tags: real-analysis

Assume that $f$ is a homeomorphism of the unit circle onto itself. If $$1/M \le \frac{|f(e^{i(t+s)})-f(e^{i(t)})|}{|f(e^{i(t)})-f(e^{i(t-s)})|}\le M,$$ then we say that $f$ is $M-$quasi-symmetric selfmapping of the unit circle onto itself. Is every smooth quasi-simmetric mapping bi-Lipschitz?

Comment: It seems that this is trivial, so you can close the question.

Comment: What does it exactly mean "smooth"?

Comment: The map $f(x)=x^3$ is quasi-symmetric and smooth on the unit interval. However, it is clearly not bi-Lipschitz. In the same fashion one gets examples for the circle.